# pyqt5でQPixmapで読み取った画像を保存したい

Tags: python, pyqt

pyqtでQPixmapで読み取った画像を、選んだフォルダー内に保存したいです。下は試しに書いてみたコードです。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *




class Main(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",20)

        global img
        img=QPixmap('グリーングリーン.jpg')
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(img)


        foldabtn=QPushButton('FldaSave')
        foldabtn.clicked.connect(self.foldasave)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(foldabtn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('text')
        self.show()

    def foldasave(self):
        foldaname=QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"save folda")
        img.save(foldaname,"JPG")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが出来ます。
[image: 画像]
ここで、Foldasaveを押して、保存するフォルダーを選んで、そこにQPixmapで読み込んだ画像を保存したいです。しかし、作成したGUIでフォルダーを選択しても何も起きません。エラーすら吐きません。どうすればよいのでしょうか。

追記：
folda関数内を

```
    foldaname=QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"save folda")
    foldaname=foldaname+"//image.jpg"
    img.save(foldaname,"JPG")
```

にしたら出来ました。

Comment: もし解決したようでしたら、質問文に追記してしまうのではなく、個別に回答として投稿してもらうと他のユーザーからも分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: そうですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

folda関数内を

```
foldaname=QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"save folda")
foldaname=foldaname+"//image.jpg"
img.save(foldaname,"JPG")
```

にしたら出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

`QPixmap`クラスの`save`メソッドに渡すのはファイル名ですので、
`QFileDialog.getSaveFileName`でファイル名を取得すればよいと思います。

```
# 例 (第3, 4, 5, 6引数は省略)
filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "save")
img.save(filename, "PNG")
```

なお、`save`メソッドが成功したかどうかは、返り値が`0`かどうかで判断できると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。しかし、pythonが動作を停止しました。また、最終的に複数の画像を一度に保存したいので、’QFileDialog.getSaveFileName’ではなく、’QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory’を使って、選んだフォルダに画像を保存したいです。